# Best approach to get ordered data from big table

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I am trying to get ordered and filtered data from a 10 million row table. The problem is very slow `ordered by` working in this case. The number of filtering combinations is very large, I cannot predict all of them to create the cache with the correct order. Also, my data can be changed often. In other words I really need to sort my data with every query.

I tried to google it and realized that indexes and other optimizations couldn't be helpful for ordering. Am I right? And what is the best way to get ordered data quickly? Is it possible in postgres? Should I use different tools for that? Maybe ETL in non-relational db or smth like that?

example of simple query:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM offers
WHERE
        offers.attributes ->> 'width' = '190'
    AND offers.attributes ->> 'height' = '55'
    AND offers.attributes ->> 'diameter' = '16'
ORDER BY price
```

explain analyze output:

```
Sort  (cost=463529.78..463529.78 rows=1 width=248) (actual time=3083.447..3084.143 rows=12420 loops=1)
  Sort Key: price
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 6530kB
  ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..463529.77 rows=1 width=248) (actual time=0.327..3078.755 rows=12420 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on offers  (cost=0.00..462529.67 rows=1 width=248) (actual time=4.826..3072.672 rows=4140 loops=3)
              Filter: (((attributes ->> 'width'::text) = '190'::text) AND ((attributes ->> 'height'::text) = '55'::text) AND ((attributes ->> 'diameter'::text) = '16'::text))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 3329193
Planning Time: 0.256 ms
Execution Time: 3084.612 ms
```

all table indexes

```
create index offers_attribu_5d15b4_gin
    on offers using gin (attributes);

create index offers_created_ae6fa523
    on offers (created);

create index offers_updated_c723e738
    on offers (updated);

create index offers_quantity_dc0026a6
    on offers (quantity);

create index offers_model_id_8846a913
    on offers (model_id);

create index offers_price_list_id_1f3d95de
    on offers (price_list_id);

create index offers_price_ids
    on offers (price);

create index offers_model_price_idx
    on offers (model_id, price);

create index offers_json_price_idx
    on offers (attributes, price);

create index offers_json_model_idx
    on offers (attributes, model_id);

create index offers_price_idx
    on offers (price);
```

Comment: "The number of filtering combinations is very large"  But what about the selectivity?  If one condition eliminates 99.999% of the data, and all the rest combined only remove 50% of what is left, you can pretty much ignore the rest of the conditions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name done

Comment: @jjanes about 100 thousand lines left after filtering

Comment: @jjanes depends of filters of course, it can be 10 000 for example, but it's still slow

Comment: In your example, the sort took much less than 1% of the total time.  Not worth worrying about.

Comment: @jjanes how did you understand that? If I remove order by i takes 200 ms. With order by - 3000 ms.

Comment: In the plan you showed us, the part before the sort took 3078.755 ms.  You didn't show us a plan with no ordering, if that one is faster maybe there were other differences besides the ordering, or maybe it just found the data already in cache and didn't need to read it from disk.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will become must faster if you rewrite it so that it can use the GIN index on the `jsonb` column:

```
SELECT *
FROM offers
WHERE attributes @> '{ "width": 190, "height": 55, "diameter": 16 }'
ORDER BY price;
```